# c++ static member function

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, static-members

I have a problem in my assignment.

The assignment is about international english chess

One of the following tasks is required to implement a static member function that returns a suitable Piece of the chess's object given the matching **PieceChar** and **Position**.

It is suggested to me that it should implement the Factory member function using a member function similar to **Clone** function but not using the Clone member function itself. The Factory should be as efficient
as possible, hence code that are infficient (e.g., in terms of multiple branching )

Here is the PieceChar Given

```
enum class PieceChar : char
{
    WHITE_PAWN = 'P',
    WHITE_KNIGHT = 'N',
    WHITE_BISHOP = 'B',
    WHITE_ROOK = 'R',
    WHITE_QUEEN = 'Q',
    WHITE_KING = 'K',

    BLACK_PAWN = 'p',
    BLACK_KNIGHT = 'n',
    BLACK_BISHOP = 'b',
    BLACK_ROOK = 'r',
    BLACK_QUEEN = 'q',
    BLACK_KING = 'k',
    EMPTY = 'e',
};
```

Here is the skeleton of some of the chess piece base of inheritance

```
 class Piece
{
public:
  Piece(Colour c, const Position& pos);
  virtual void GenMoves(const Board &, std::vector<Move>& ) const = 0;
  Colour colour() const;
  void position(const Position& pos);
  const Position& position() const;
  virtual Piece* Clone() const = 0;
  static Piece* Factory(PieceChar, const Position& pos);
  virtual ~Piece();
private:
  Colour piece_colour;
  Position piece_pos;
};

class Pawn: public Piece
{
public:
  Pawn(Colour c, const Position& pos);
  ~Pawn();
  void GenMoves(const Board &, std::vector<Move>& ) const override;
  Piece* Clone() const override;
};
```

I have trouble of implement this following function

```
 static Piece* Factory(PieceChar, const Position& pos);
```

Any tip or guide to tackle this question, I am not sure where can I ask the question beside here.

If you require more information, feel free to ask.

**addon: i can't modify given declaration, but i can only allow add more helper function.**

Comment: Don't return a `Piece*`, return `std::shared_ptr<Piece>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I am stuck" is not a question. Please formulate a problem statement which is in the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework ;)
what you are probably looking for is "What is a static function in a c++ class?"

Answer (score 0):

Simple switch does the job:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Piece> Piece::Factory(PieceChar type, const Position& pos)
{
    switch (type) {
        case PieceChar::WHITE_PAWN: return std::make_unique<Pawn>(Colour::White, pos);
        case PieceChar::WHITE_KNIGHT: return std::make_unique<Knight>(Colour::White, pos);
        case PieceChar::WHITE_BISHOP: return std::make_unique<Bishop>(Colour::White, pos);
        case PieceChar::WHITE_ROOK: return std::make_unique<Rook>(Colour::White, pos);
        case PieceChar::WHITE_QUEEN: return std::make_unique<Queen>(Colour::White, pos);
        case PieceChar::WHITE_KING: return std::make_unique<King>(Colour::White, pos);

        case PieceChar::BLACK_PAWN: return std::make_unique<Pawn>(Colour::Black, pos);
        case PieceChar::BLACK_KNIGHT: return std::make_unique<Knight>(Colour::Black, pos);
        case PieceChar::BLACK_BISHOP: return std::make_unique<Bishop>(Colour::Black, pos);
        case PieceChar::BLACK_ROOK: return std::make_unique<Rook>(Colour::Black, pos);
        case PieceChar::BLACK_QUEEN: return std::make_unique<Queen>(Colour::Black, pos);
        case PieceChar::BLACK_KING: return std::make_unique<King>(Colour::Black, pos);
        case PieceChar::EMPTY: throw std::runtime_error("invalid type");
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("unknown type");
}
```

Comment: Hello thank for the solution, i forget add 1 more point, that i can't modify the given declaration of the function, right now it will cause memory leak i guess, if i return  new Pawn(Colour::White, pos); instead.

Comment: With given signature, ownership is clear, if you return raw pointer, you have to call delete on it manually.